# buttons become disabled/blocked after switching views?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have two UIViews that are subviews of the root controllers view. In my app the user is able to switch between these views whenever a button is pressed. To do this I set one views hidden property to yes and the other to no. both views (lets say view A and view B) have several buttons but when I switch from view A to view B and back to view A the buttons on view A no longer work as in they do not receive  touch up inside action (the only action I have set up). Also if change the layering so that I start on view B, when I switch to view A, the buttons also do not work. This is not the case for view B the buttons for view B continue to work after having changed views.

here is the code I have for switching my views:

```
_calculatorView.hidden = YES;
_converterView.hidden = NO;

CGFloat scale = (280/_item2.frame.size.width);
[UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
    _item1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item1.transform, scale, scale);
    _item1.alpha = 0;
    _item2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item2.transform, scale, scale);
    _item2.alpha = 0;
    _item3.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(_item3.transform, scale, scale);
    _item3.alpha = 0;
    _menuBackground.alpha = 0;
}];

menuAlpha = 0;
```

This button switches from view A to view B
another button with almost identical code switches from view B to view A.

So what could be causing my buttons on view A to suddenly stop working? is it a layering thing or what?

I have also tried using sendSubviewToBack in order to switch views but this results in the same problem.

Edit:

There are a total of 4 views on top of the view that is having the problem (1 image view and 3 buttons) these four views act as a menu and can be faded in and out but always remain on top of every other view. The buttons are used to switch between views A and B and a third view is currently inactive but will provide the same purpose. I already had a touch gesture set up with the image view but it only served to fade out the menu views so I added the following if statement to see if it was activated.

```
NSLog(@"Gesture is activated");
```

This confirmed that the menu views are not blocking the buttons from being activated.

I also discovered that just by fading in the menu the buttons "brake" so it must be connected to it somehow.

Comment: I can see alpha to be set to zero, Is there any other view with alpha 0 on top of the view? Write a touches begin method on ViewA and see whether touches begin is called?

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR I found the problem, I use a pinch gesture to fade in my menu (see edit) and hidden inside the gesture recognizer I had a line of code that disables user interaction for the view that contains the buttons. I don't remember how it got there but it did. Without your suggestion I may not have discovered this for several days so I appreciate it.